# This proof is wrong. How? (See image in link below)

Tags: pi

Came across this on the internet. I have some ideas regarding this but I wanted to know more such reasonings.
[image: Proof of Pi]

Comment: Came across what?

Comment: Sorry missed the picture earlier. Edited it now.

Comment: Vi Hart had a video on Pi being equal to 4. You should watch it.

Comment: The step "repeat to infinity" should immediately make you suspicious. I've heard someone is still trying to catch a tortoise with that one.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjHgdnm3dbTAhVHjlQKHWVVAsUQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmath.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F43118%2Fhow-to-convince-a-layman-that-the-pi-4-proof-is-wrong&usg=AFQjCNEV7t_AG5bziCmGqDgI8iHsuyMGoA)

Comment: @ClementC. yeah . . .

Comment: This has been explained on MSE before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, you have jumped in without a definition of the length of an arc.

The circumference isn't approximated by the sum of lengths of the lines drawn as shown in the image, but by the sum of the hypotenuses of the right-angled triangles formed around the edge of the circle.